# Loop through dataframe and plot time series based on common column

Tags: r, plot

So I have a dataframe that has a Plate ID, Time Point, Substrate, and Mean Values for two readings (made up data):

```
Plate_ID    Day    Name           590_Mean    590_SD    750_Mean    750_Mean
MCBA15 001  0      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 001  1      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
MCBA15 001  3      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
...
MCBA15 001  10     Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 005  0      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 005  1      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
MCBA15 005  3      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
...
MCBA15 005  10     Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 001  0      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 001  1      Lactose        0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
MCBA15 001  3      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
...
MCBA15 001  10     Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 005  0      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
MCBA15 005  1      Lactose        0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
MCBA15 005  3      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
...
MCBA15 005  10     Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
```

There are 32 substrates per Plate_ID and each Plate has 7 Day readings.

Ideally, I want to plot the 590 and 750 Mean values on the same time series over the 10 day period (7 readings) with standard deviation bars (time intervals = 1 day).

I was able to generate one such graph, but this was going in and sorting the data. I then took the following approach:

```
library('Hmisc')

x <- sortbiolog$Day[1:7]
y <- sortbiolog$X750_Mean[1:7]
sd <- sortbiolog$X750_SD[1:7]

plot(x, y, type = "b", ylim = c(0,.3))
with(
  data = sortbiolog,
  expr = errbar(x, y, y + sd, y - sd, add = T, pch =1, cap = .01), main = "?-Cyclodextrin Substrate for MCBA15 001")

par(new=TRUE)

a <- sortbiolog$Day[1:7]
b <- sortbiolog$X590_Mean[1:7]
ab_sd <- sortbiolog$X590_SD[1:7]

plot(a, b, type = "b", ylim = c(0,.3))
with(
  data = sortbiolog,
  expr = errbar(a, b, b + ab_sd, b - ab_sd, add = T, pch =1, cap = .01, col="red", axis=FALSE))

legend('topright', legend=c("Mean 750", "Mean 590"), text.col=c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

However, I was wondering if there was a way to loop through the data and create these images based on the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat <- read.table(header = TRUE, text="Plate_ID    Day    Name           590_Mean    590_SD    750_Mean    750_SD
'MCBA15 001'  0      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  1      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  2      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  3      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  5      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  7      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  10     Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  0      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  1      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  2      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  3      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  5      Cyclodextrin   0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  7      Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  10     Cyclodextrin   0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  0      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  1      Lactose        0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  2      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  3      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  5      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  7      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 001'  10     Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  0      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  1      Lactose        0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  2      Lactose        0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  3      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  5      Lactose        0.257       0.012     0.171       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  7      Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012
'MCBA15 005'  10     Lactose        0.217       0.012     0.161       0.012")
```

There are several things in this function that are not necessary (like the indexing) but I wanted to change as little from your code as I could to show you the general approach. So here is your code wrapped into a function which takes a single data frame.

```
f <- function(sortbiolog) {
  require('Hmisc')

  x <- sortbiolog$Day[1:7]
  y <- sortbiolog$X750_Mean[1:7]
  sd <- sortbiolog$X750_SD[1:7]

  plot(x, y, type = "b", ylim = c(0,.3))
  with(
    data = sortbiolog,
    expr = errbar(x, y, y + sd, y - sd, add = T, pch =1, cap = .01), main = "?-Cyclodextrin Substrate for MCBA15 001")

  par(new=TRUE)

  a <- sortbiolog$Day[1:7]
  b <- sortbiolog$X590_Mean[1:7]
  ab_sd <- sortbiolog$X590_SD[1:7]

  plot(a, b, type = "b", ylim = c(0,.3), ann = FALSE)
  with(
    data = sortbiolog,
    expr = errbar(a, b, b + ab_sd, b - ab_sd, add = T, pch =1, cap = .01, col="red"))

  legend('bottomright', legend=c("Mean 750", "Mean 590"), text.col=c("black", "red"))
}
```

So you could still use this on your full data like `f(dat[1:7, ])`, but instead of fooling with indexing, you split the original into a list of data frames based on the `Plate_ID` and `Name`:

```
sp <- split(dat, with(dat, interaction(Plate_ID, Name)))

sapply(sp, dim)

#      MCBA15 001.Cyclodextrin MCBA15 005.Cyclodextrin MCBA15 001.Lactose MCBA15 005.Lactose
# [1,]                       7                       7                  7                  7
# [2,]                       7                       7                  7                  7
```

And then apply the function over a list:

```
pdf('~/desktop/tmp.pdf')
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
p <- lapply(sp, f)
dev.off()
```

Gives me

[image]

Comment: thanks! after some minor tweaking, I got exactly what I was looking for. This was a HUGE help!